# what is getNodeID() in BranchCallback

Tags: visual-c++, cplex

I want to retrieve the value of Node and NodeID in CPLEX through callbacks in c++. I use getNodeid() in BranchCallback but it wasn't true.Because the value of this function is different from the value of NodeID in logfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by `getNodeId()` is different from what is displayed in the `NodeID` column in the log.

- `getNodeId()` returns the sequence number of a node. That number is a unique id that is created/set when the node is created.
- `NodeID` in the log returns the id of a node. The id is assigned when the node is processed. In a single-threaded run the root node has id 0, the next node processed has id 1, the next node has id 2 etc.

So the two values are unrelated.